# java, can't add elements in vector (size 0)

Tags: java, vector, size

Im kinda lost, i havent coded for months and I cant figure out why size return 0... I clearly added elements in the constructor right

```
package com.data;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Vector;
import com.vols.Vol;

public class InfosVols {

    public static Vector<Vol> listeVol = new Vector<Vol>();

    public InfosVols(){
        listeVol.addElement(new Vol(999999,"Montreal", "Toronto", false, new Date(), 9, 3));
        listeVol.addElement(new Vol(111,"Montreal", "Toronto", false, new Date(), 9, 3));
        listeVol.addElement(new Vol(112,"Montreal", "Toronto", false, new Date(), 10, 3));
        listeVol.addElement(new Vol(121,"Montreal", "Vancouveur", false, new Date(), 8, 5));
        listeVol.addElement(new Vol(131,"Montreal", "Calgary", false, new Date(), 14, 3));
        listeVol.addElement(new Vol(132,"Montreal", "Calgary", false, new Date(), 16, 3));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(listeVol.size());
    }
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You never call `InfosVols` (or more to the point, create a new instance of `InfosVols`)

Start by removing the static reference to `listeVol`, then construct a new instance of `InfosVols`

```
InfosVols vols = new InfosVols();
```

Then trying using the newly created instance of `InfosVols` (and the instance field) to print the size of the `Vector`

```
System.out.println(vols.listeVol.size());
```

I should probably also point out the `Vector` has been "deprecated" in favour of the [collections API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/) `List` interface.

Answer (score 1):

The elements are added in constructor of class InfosVols. There isn't a call to the constructor (ie. making an instance of InfoVols). Hence there are no elements added into the vector.

Answer (score 1):

You have not called the constructor which adds the elements.
Try calling new before size:

```
new InfosVols();
System.out.println(listeVol.size());
```

It is not very clear what you are trying to achieve but this kind of design is dangerous. With every new call to the constructor you add further elements to the static (global) variable listeVol. You probably do not want the listeVol to be static.

Comment: You should note that while `listeVol` remains `static`, each new instance of `InfosVols` will add (or modify) the same list, meaning that if the OP creates two instances of `InfosVols`, they will end up with twice as many entries...

Answer (score 1):

This is what was ran

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(listeVol.size());
}
```

Which needed the static environment to be constructed prior to running, so *in order* this is all of what was ran

```
public static Vector<Vol> listeVol = new Vector<Vol>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(listeVol.size());
}
```

Which means you never constructed a `InfosVols` and never called this code

```
public InfosVols(){
    listeVol.addElement(new Vol(999999,"Montreal", "Toronto", false, new Date(), 9, 3));
    listeVol.addElement(new Vol(111,"Montreal", "Toronto", false, new Date(), 9, 3));
    listeVol.addElement(new Vol(112,"Montreal", "Toronto", false, new Date(), 10, 3));
    listeVol.addElement(new Vol(121,"Montreal", "Vancouveur", false, new Date(), 8, 5));
    listeVol.addElement(new Vol(131,"Montreal", "Calgary", false, new Date(), 14, 3));
    listeVol.addElement(new Vol(132,"Montreal", "Calgary", false, new Date(), 16, 3));
}
```

If you add

```
new InfosVols();
```

into the parts that are already called, you would have had the expected results.

Comment: You should note that while `listeVol` remains `static`, each new instance of `InfosVols` will add (or modify) the same list, meaning that if the OP creates two instances of `InfosVols`, they will end up with twice as many entries...

Answer (score 0):

You never call the constructor, so the static attribute is never initialized. Plus, don't use `Vector` it's an old class, prefer `ArrayList` (or another `List` implementation depending on your needs).

I'm not sure you really want to have this attribute static, nor that you really want to initialize it in a constructor.